# How can I check if other packages in my React Native project require Swift support after removing a feature that previously enabled it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, dependency-management

I added a feature which had [react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service) as a dependency to my React Native app a while back. `react-native-geolocation-service` required me to [enable Swift support](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/HEAD/docs/setup.md#2-enable-swift-support) in iOS.

I just removed that feature from my app and want to know if I can disable Swift support too. To do this I need to check if any current dependencies require Swift support in my React Native project (various other developers have added features and dependencies).

One way would be to disable swift support and run the iOS app to see if it crashes, but this is less than ideal. Is there a way to check this either through my code, node modules, pods or by using Xcode. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging into Swift and Xcode and found out how to do this but couldn't find a question on StackOverflow for this. To find out if your iOS project and any of its dependencies require Swift support, you can check the Xcode "Link Binary With Libraries" project configuration by following the below steps:

1. Open your React Native project in Xcode by opening the .xcworkspace file.
2. Select your project's root file (blue icon) in the Xcode project navigator on the left-hand side
3. Click on the "Build Phases" tab in the main editor area.
4. Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, which lists the libraries and frameworks your project depends on.
5. Look for any libraries or frameworks with a .framework extension that have the Swift logo (a white circle with a blue background and an "S" in the centre) next to them. These are the packages that require Swift support.
6. Take note of the Swift-dependent packages you find. You can check the associated library names or framework names and search for their corresponding React Native packages to determine which packages rely on Swift.